# Python Tkinter app with text widget bidi rtl writing

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget

I'm trying to make a Text widget that will let the user write Hebrew words from right to left. after searching in different similar question that were asked on stack overflow about this topic, I didn't find any solution for what I need. is there a way to add to the `tk.tex`t widget an option to imbed writing text from right-to-left?
Here is a snippet code for the text widget:

```
text_widget = tk.Text(canvas, width=60, height=6, wrap='word', font=('calibri','13'))
text_widget.tag_configure('right', justify='right')
text_widget.insert('insert', default_val, 'right')
text_widget.config(highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground='#D4D700', 
highlightcolor='#D4D700')
canvas.create_window(300, 340, window=text_widget)
```

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Considering everything in python is an object (list) you can use
`var = 'word'
var = var[::-1]
print(var)`
Output > drow

Comment: But if I'll use the reverse option it will make the words messy. when I'm writing in the text editor the words are written fine. it's just aligning the text on the left side of the text widget and not on the right side as you write in Hebrew. I just want to start the writing form the right and not from the left.

Comment: You said that you looked at other question. Can you show us a [mre] taken from another question and say what exactly isn't working? There are a lot of questions with different answers, which ones have you tried and why do you not like those answers?